# magento default zoom function not working on initial page load

Tags: magento-1.9, zoom

I'm running magento ce 1.9.1 and, on initial page load, the zoom function is not working until either a thumbnail is clicked or the browser window is resized. The only difference I can see is that the zoom container is not present initially. Please see my demo page at https://streetmatsuri.com/index.php/gen-2-0/nrg-quick-release-gen-3-0.html Any help would be appreciated; thanks in advance.